# What are guidelines of whether to throw an exception in C++ standard function?

Tags: c++, exception

I have found out that C++ standard functions show very different behavior when having an exception. This seem to contradict its touting of "try/throw/catch". Can anyone please briefly explain what are the C++ designer's reasoning behind these choices?

1. Do nothing, for example, try to pop() a stack when it is empty (instead of throw a range_error), do sqrt(-1) (instead of throw a domain_error)
2. Return a zero pointer: for example, when doing illegal pointer downcasting (interesting, doing an illegal reference downcasting will throw a bad_cast)
3. Throw an exception, but this appear to a minority of functions, for example, substr()
4. Give user a choice of whether to throw an exception, for example, new() will throw bad_alloc() when out of memory, but you can also choose (nothrow) as an option of new().

Comment: What has your question to do with "*handling* an exception"? You only talk about whether error conditions *throw* an exception!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the behaviour of C++ library functions can be explained by the general C++ philosophy "you don't pay for what you don't use". That means that any particular construction shouldn't incur any unneeded overhead when you use it correctly.

Optionally, more expensive, checked versions may exist, such as `std::vector::at()`, but it is up to you whether or not to use them.

The example of `stack::pop()` and `sqrt()` shows this philosophy in action: In order to throw an exception on error, you would *always* have to check whether the call is valid. This check is unnecessary if you already know that your call will succeed, so there is no mandatory check built into those functions. If you want a check, you can write one yourself.

The default `new` is slightly different, as it incorporates facilities for calling a `new_handler`, and so the checking is done anyway. (Recall that an exception is only expensive if you actually throw it, so that aspect isn't so important.) If you wanted to, you could always replace your own global `operator new()` by one which literally just forwards the argument to `malloc()`. (That would of course make it unsafe to use the default `new` expression, as you have no way of checking now that you can construct an object at the returned pointer. So you'll end up writing a check yourself and using placement-new, which is almost exactly what the nothrow-version does.)

Answer (score 2):

> Return a zero pointer: for example, when doing illegal pointer downcasting (interesting, doing an illegal reference downcasting will throw a bad_cast)

`dynamic_cast` provides an way to check the validity of the cast. It is by no means an exception as such.With pointers the cast returns a `NULL` because throwing an exception would be an overhead and the same can be achieved by returning a `NULL`, With the restriction that References cannot be `NULL`, there was no option but to throw an exception, there was no other way to return the result to user in this case.

> Give user a choice of whether to throw an exception, for example, new() will throw bad_alloc() when out of memory, but you can also choose (nothrow) as an option of new().

Long ago `new` just returned NULL as in case of `malloc`, but later on it was standardized to throw an `bad_alloc` exception, This would have meant all the code previously written using `new` would have to be modified to a large extent to handle the exception, to avoid this and maintain a compatibility the nothrow version of new was introduced.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer downcasts returning null is a simpler and faster way to test whether a given object is of the given subclass. I.e. you can write stuff like `if (dynamic_cast<A*>(v) || dynamic_cast<B*>(v))`, or `if (A* a = dynamtic_cast<A*>(v)) doStuffWith(a);`, which would've been cumbersome with exceptions. Here you actually expect casts to fail, while exceptions are exceptional by their nature, in that they are supposed to rarely be thrown during the normal execution of your program.

In other cases explicit checks for incorrect values may be omitted just for performance reasons. C++ is supposed to be efficient, instead of attempting to prevent one from shooting himself in the leg.

Answer (score 1):

Most of this depends on whether there are enough appropriate return values to express the "failure" conditions and whether those values are convenient or not.

#### Rationale behind cited examples

`std::stack<>::pop()` does not throw an error because it doesn't have an error value and it simplifies calling code.  It might not be an application logic error to attempt to pop an empty stack.

`std::sqrt()` has an appropriate value (not a number) which was included in floating point representations precisely for this purpose.  It also has the benefit of propagating cleanly through other computations.

`dynamic_cast<>` on pointer types returns a null pointer to indicate a failed cast because the null pointer is already a standard way to represent "points to nothing".  However, there is no such equivalent for references, so it *must* throw an exception as the return value cannot be used to indicate an error.

In contrast, `std::string::substr()` can't return an empty string to represent failure as an empty string is a valid sub-string of all strings.

`new` throwing `std::bad_alloc` or not seems to have historical roots, but, like `dynamic_cast<>` on pointers, it might be convenient for some code that would try alternatives not to pay for exception handling.

Comment: The precondition for pop_back() of the default stack container(deque) is !empty(), so it is always an error to pop it if empty. Its likely that c++ tries to avoid the overhead added by checking the precondition(example vector[] vs. vector.at())

Comment: Your rational for `pop` makes no sense.  It is *always* an error to pop an empty stack, given that [in C++] it results in undefined behavior.  And exceptions don't complicate calling code in the slightest... if you aren't prepared to handle the error, the calling code is the same with or without exceptions.  Also, the return value of `sqrt(-1)` is implementation defined; NaN is not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose: Indeed, "not a number" is not guaranteed, since the standard does not assume that IEEE754 is available (or efficient) on the implementation.  However, all IEEE754 compliant implementations are required to return "not a number" for `sqrt(-N)`.  As for the `std::stack<>::pop()`, I don't have a copy of the standard at hand, but the behevior your reported is not documented on the SGI STL site, CppReference or CPlusPlus dot com.  It is not reported for member functions `.pop_back()` for `std::vector<>` and `std::list<>` either.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose: if it is not an application error to pop an empty stack, `std::stack<>::pop()` not throwing an error *does* simplify code, since it avoids writing a dummy exception block to explicitly silence the exception.

Comment: @AndréCaron: The precondition for `pop_back` [and other such functions] is that the container not be empty.  Any time you violate a precondition put forth by the standard, the result is undefined.  I don't know how you define "application error", but an action that puts your program in an indeterminate state sure sounds bad to me.  And if you feel compelled to put a dummy exception block around every function that potentially throws, you're using exceptions wrong.  This isn't Java, and its okay to let exceptions propagate.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose: I just stated that the behavior is not well documented in practically available references.  Invoking undefined behavior is obviously an application error.  However, I meant "application error" in the sense of "error with respect to a logical stack in the application".  For instance, a path may be represented as a stack and trying to remove the last component of a path may or may not be considered an error for the application that manipulates a directory tree.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose: In any case, I never said I feel compelled to put a try-catch block around every function that potentially throws.  I said that I consider it move convenient for `.pop()` ignore pop requests on empty stacks than to throw an exception.  In the case were you don't consider attempting to pop an error, it's more effiecient for `.pop()` to ignore instead of throw (and in any case, the throwing behavior can always be layered on top).  Precisely the fac that I want to avoid dummy try blocks should mean something.

Answer (score 1):

The c++ standard library is designed to be efficient, it avoids unnecessary runtime checks when possible.

1 Contains violations on the preconditions on very small/fast methods, checking these preconditions would most likely take longer than executing the methods themselves (pop is most likely a single decrement on a stack of simple types).

2 dynamic_cast checks and casts a given pointer to a compatible type. There is no separate way of only checking if a cast is possible since it would have to do the same work as the cast. Since c++ provides no separate way to only check if the cast is possible we have to expect that it may fail and it has a good error value to use when it fails (NULL). The reference version has to throw an exception as it cannot return an error value.

3 substr guarantees an exception, this may be for two reasons. One: the substr method is quite a bit more complex and slow than the methods mentioned in 1 and therefor the overhead of checking the precondition is negligible. Two: string processing is one of the biggest contributors to security holes as you are most likely processing user input, checking for overflows or out of bounds access is necessary to keep the process secure/stable. The c-library provides fast, unchecked and insecure methods to manipulate strings for those who need the speed.

4 new has to check whether it can return an address or fail in both cases, since running out of memory is unexpected by most applications the exception is reasonable. However you can write c++ while using a small subset of its features and many projects do not use exceptions as making your code exception safe is hard (especially if you use third party libraries which are not), since new is a central part of c++ an exception free implementation becomes necessary.